# How do I quickly navigate to a full path using the "Files" program?

Tags: nautilus, directory, navigation

I have this path I want to navigate to in the UI. `/usr/local/sbin`

How can I do that with a couple clicks in the UI?

Often Files shows the path as a dropdown. How can I select the path so I can copy it?
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not "*with a couple clicks*" but you can do that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> keys.

This combination would show the address-bar where you can put the path and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the directory.

You can also show the address-bar from the GUI (look for something like "*enter location*" option).