# How to show address bar in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

In my Ubuntu the address is shown as this:

[image]

**How to configure it to show the editable textbox in address bar like this?**

[image]

The pic is from here: https://www.pakzilla.com/2018/05/24/the-easiest-way-to-create-desktop-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I quickly navigate to a full path using the "Files" program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085255/how-do-i-quickly-navigate-to-a-full-path-using-the-files-program) && https://askubuntu.com/q/101100/480481